# Is boost::fast_pool_allocator using null_mutex safe in the presence of allocator rebinding?

Tags: c++, boost, allocator

I was wondering about the safety of using `boost::fast_pool_allocator` with `null_mutex` set.

I know that the following is an unsafe instance. An allocator is instantiated per type. So if you have two containers which both use `fast_pool_allocator<int, …null_mutex>` (say), they will both share the same allocator instance, and hence invite data races.

A greater concern is the following. The allocator interface allows rebinding. This means that even though you think you are using the `fast_pool_allocator` with a ‘local’ type which is unlikely to collide with other instances, a container is free to rebind that allocator to a different type, such as a global one, which does collide.

So the question is: Just how safe is `boost::fast_pool_allocator` with `null_mutex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that both pool_allocator and fast_pool_allocator are thread safe,

from: http://www.boost.org/libs/pool/doc/html/header/boost/pool/pool_alloc_hpp.html

> pool_allocator and pool_allocator will both
>   allocate/deallocate from/to the same pool.

As will the fast_pool_allocator

> If there is only one thread running before main() starts and after
>   main() ends, then both allocators are completely thread-safe.

however they are not very performant compared to other ways of decreasing allocation overhead. I have also been looking at tcmalloc from google which creates per thread heaps to avoid locking.

> The default for this  parameter is boost::details::pool::default_mutex
>   which is a synonym for either
>   boost::details::pool::null_mutex  (when threading support is
>   turned off in the compiler (so BOOST_HAS_THREADS is not set), or
>   threading support  has ben explicitly disabled with
>   BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS (Boost-wide disabling of threads) or
>   BOOST_POOL_NO_MT (this library only))  or for boost::mutex
>   (when threading support is enabled in the compiler).

```
boost::mutex
```

was set for me which is why in my threaded tests I had no issue - I would guess that this will be set correctly for you also.

**But if not then you could have an issue because:**

> Since the size of T is used to determine the type of the underlying
>   Pool, each allocator for different types of the same size will share
>   the same underlying pool. The tag class prevents pools from being
>   shared between pool_allocator and fast_pool_allocator. For example, on
>   a system where sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *), pool_allocator and
>   pool_allocator will both allocate/deallocate from/to the same
>   pool.

Comment: See the declaration of fast_pool_allocator: `template<typename T, typename UserAllocator, typename Mutex, 
           unsigned NextSize, unsigned MaxSize> 
    class fast_pool_allocator;` It takes a Mutex template argument. I can either use the default or I can pass the null mutex object in which case it turns off mutex locking for the allocator. The STL compliant way is to pass an allocator that is thread-safe.

Comment: See my update - I'm not guessing I have recent experience with boost pool which indicated that it was synchronised.

Comment: In my case, I have a multi-threaded server and potentially multiple threads. I have one thread using a boost::fast_pool_allocator with type Data1. I have another thread using a boost::fast_pool_allocator with type Data2. Is there any chance that a rebind could occur that would rebind these allocators to a primitive like unsigned and lead to a cast where I am accessing the same underlying allocator from both threads? In such a case the lack of mutex would cause badness.

Comment: well it is defined on type T, but the pool is shared with other types (Q) where sizeof(T) == sizeof(Q). So if your impl does use null_mutex then it will be a problem

Comment: Ah is it just the size that matters? Could I guarantee safety by doing this? `struct LocalType1 { uint32_t data; };` and then another `struct LocalType2 { uint32_t data; };`. Then use different fast_pool_allocators with null_mutex for both?